# Difference between "if + negative" and "if + positive" in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Any semantic difference between the two following sentences?

> See if there isn't any room for improvement.
>
> See if there is any room for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native speaker - I think these are basically equivalent. In both cases, the imperative is to check whether room for improvement exists, so the activity is the same.

There's a *slight* difference of tone. I would normally use "see if there isn't" in cases where *I think* there is room for improvement but I'm speaking to someone who disagrees; the implication is that I want them to conduct a more thorough search. But "see if there is" is also correct in that case.

I think you're good either way.

Comment: I'd personally read "See if there isn't any room for improvement" as "I don't expect there to be any room for improvement, but check just in case". (non-native speaker here, so take it with a grain of salt)

Comment: @MaciejStachowski -- interesting, your implication is the opposite of mine. :) No grains of salt necessary, I'm sure this is just idiosyncratic. Maybe I'm the only one who thinks of the difference this way!

Comment: I'm not sure I hear much difference in meaning, but the first one sounds more British and the second more American to me.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Thanks for the input. The sentence with a negative was actually from something a mod wrote on this site to suggest "There should be room for improvement, so don't blame other people." I think it may depend on the context and dialect, as Canadian Yankee suggests.